# Serving Ember and Lumen From Cloud 9 Workspace

Tags: ember.js, cloud9-ide, ports, lumen

I'm testing out Cloud 9 and am running into an issue with ports. According to C9 docs ports I can bind to are 8080, 8081 and 8082. I've created a sample Ember app that's being served via ember-cli on port 8080, and when I visit it via `<workspace>-<username>.c9.io:8080` everything works fine.

I'm also trying to serve a test Lumen application as an API server for this simple app on port 8081 using `php artisan serve --port 8081`. Testing API calls via wget on terminal in C9 works, but I can't access the server via `<workspace>-<username>.c9.io:8081` and proxying to `http://localhost:8081` via `.ember-cli` config file results in ECONNREFUSED errors.

Do I need to enable or modify something else in my C9 workspace to run this properly in a single workspace?

Comment: Does the lumen application work if you do `curl localhost:8081` in your workspace? You don't need any additional config to use the extra external ports with Cloud9. Also make sure it's binding to port 0.0.0.0. If it's binding to 127.0.0.1 it won't be available externally.

Comment: Hey @Tim, thanks for the heads-up on 0.0.0.0. IP address! By default lumen/laravel is served on 127.0.0.1. Running `php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=0881` works nicely! Feel free to post an answer and I'll accept it. Thank again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please ensure Lumen is binding to port 0.0.0.0. If it's binding to 127.0.0.1 it won't be externally accessible.